# Cloning 2.5" laptop HDD and SSD fast over multiple laptops?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, clone

I noticed that simple USB data transfer may encounter heat problems because the newer models have no separate line for energy as some XYZ-other-cord. Today, I received a box full of Seagate FreeAgent GoFlex FireWire 800 -cables. My task is to upgrade SSDs/HDDs meaning that the old content needs to be transferred unchanged to newer drives, how?

Specs:

1. a flock of ThinkPads x60s and x60 -- now upgraded into x220
2. OCZ Agility 3 120 GB 2.5" SSD SATA III upgraded into Intel 320 SSDs
3. a variety of HDDs possible in some laptops

Comment: @Shinrai: thank you for the notice. Killed the junk. Look this question is not easy and I have no idea how ask this properly -- I even just found out that USB is not ideal cable for fast data transfer of a massive amount of drives to new ones. I know that FireWire has some promises but I would like to get this thing go fast and without my clicking things with software. Perhaps some hardware level setup to get A drive content into B drive?

Comment: Can you provide the make model of the laptops?  Make/Model of the SSD drives?

Comment: Do you have access to any additional hardware?  Any desktop PCs?  Honestly, the easiest way to do this in a reasonable amount of time per system without shelling out for professional drive duplicator equipment is probably slaving the drives up to a desktop or on an eSATA dock or something like that and just doing a disk-to-disk clone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions using methods that have worked well for me many times

These solutions will require a USB to SATA adapter.  There are many available but your location might dictate what is easy to get. [USB-SATA adapter images](http://www.google.ca/search?q=usb%20sata%20adapter&hl=en&prmd=imvnsfd&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=AXcxT5TcJKH00gHD6-T6Bw&sqi=2&ved=0CGIQsAQ&biw=1680&bih=881).  Startech is a common one here in North America. [Startech USB-SATA adapter](http://www.startech.com/HDD/Adapters/USB-20-to-IDE-or-SATA-Adapter-Cable~USB2SATAIDE)

Given the drive does not ship with cloning software, I would suggest something like Symantec/Norton GHOST and simply attach the SSD via USB/Firewire or whatever you have and then boot with GHOST. You can then clone the drive from the laptop to the SSD and all data will transfer.

You could also use Symantec System Recovery and image the drive using that in a similar way to GHOST  If you are cloning from the X60 series to the newer X220 then System Recovery is a great tool as it will restore to different hardware.  It works very well.

Not sure what the heat problem is you mention.  Can you elaborate?  Not sure what "no separate line for energy as some XYZ-other-cord"  means.  I have transfered many systems using the above tools and not had any issue.

Comment: I got a bit cheaper cables, thanks for the tip +1. Automounting works in Ubuntu and Windows so the cables should work but some diffuculties in mounting, more [here](http://superuser.com/questions/397646/windows-7-filesystem-and-backuping-it-in-ix). I tried to create the backup media in Windows directly but some strip-offed closed-software and diffuculties with it. Then I had no external HDD, no disks so I am now trying to backup the media to my server with the instructions [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11028/backup-whole-hard-disk-linux).

Answer (score 0):

Given what I believe your question to be, have you considered a drive cloning device instead of laplink style direct connections?  Drive cloning is much much faster, and also substantially easier to configure and execute.

Comment: laplink -style? Some citations would be useful...

Comment: laplink-style refers to the use of a USB or other cable directly connected between two devices.

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way to clone is to use a Windows desktop PC with multiple (at least 4) sata connections on the motherboard, connect drives to the extra sata ports on the motherboard, boot into windows and clone using your favorite clone software for windows, it will be so much faster cloning over a sata bus compared to usb.

Answer (score 0):

eSata instead of USB possibly?

Have you considered Multicast? Do the clients have the same information? Clonezilla SE would be good.

Even if you have to do them one at a time [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) is a great option.