# Cloning Fresh Windows 7 -fsed HDD to Linux Server because having no external HDD or disks for the Backup

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, backup, ntfs, clone

New lenovo x220 laptop with Windows 7 Pro with the below specs. I want to backup the disk to my server but I need to know the W7 fs, what is it?

```
$ sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb Windows/
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
$ sudo mount -t ntf /dev/sdb Windows/
mount: unknown filesystem type 'ntf'
$ sudo mount -t nts /dev/sdb Windows/
mount: unknown filesystem type 'nts'

$ dmesg|tail
[   25.928832] sdb: p2 size 4779917312 extends beyond EOD, truncated
[   25.928867] sdb: p3 start 4804509696 is beyond EOD, truncated
[   25.929882] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 78142806 4096-byte logical blocks: (320 GB/298 GiB)
[   25.931382] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present
[   25.931387] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[   25.931392] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[   27.960028] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
[  174.655199] EXT3-fs (sdb): error: can't find ext3 filesystem on dev sdb.
[  174.657319] EXT2-fs (sdb): error: can't find an ext2 filesystem on dev sdb.
[  174.660818] EXT4-fs (sdb): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
```

**Perhaps related**

1. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11028/backup-whole-hard-disk-linux
2. USB-SATA adapter -suggestion to connect the new HDD to my *ix laptop, https://superuser.com/a/387134/114739
3. I am using these SATA to HDD 2.5" Adapters [here](http://www.dealextreme.com/p/usb-sata-ide-cable-set-474?r=36798618) and [here](http://www.dealextreme.com/p/usb-2-0-to-all-2-5-3-5-ide-sata-hdd-adapter-37953?r=36798618), bought two pieces but both seems to work at least automounting works with them in Ubuntu and Windows.

**To Luke's comment**

```
$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 60.0 GB, 60022480896 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7297 cylinders, total 117231408 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000da58e

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   113055743    56526848   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       113057790   117229567     2085889    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       113057792   117229567     2085888   82  Linux swap / Solaris
Note: sector size is 4096 (not 512)

Disk /dev/sdb: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 4864 cylinders, total 78142806 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x181d6d22

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048     3074047    12288000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2         3074048   600563711  2389958656    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3       600563712   625139711    98304000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

**Err to Lamar's comment**

```
root@h:/# mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb2 /Windows/
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb2': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb2' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
root@h:/# sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb2 /Windows/
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb2': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb2' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?

$ sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb2 /Windows
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb2': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb2' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

Comment: Isn't /dev/sdb the entire disk, instead of /dev/sdb1 or /dev/sdb2? What does `fdisk -l` output?

Comment: Yeah, the filesystem of the primary installation should be NTFS.

Comment: No, it hasn't changed.  It will be changing with Windows 8 but ReFS is supposed to look exactly like NTFS to any API that's accessing it so everything that already reads NTFS should continue to read NTFS (although some low-level stuff might not work properly, obviously)

Comment: sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb2 /windows
slashes are important

Comment: In the question you never have a partition number after the drive letter. And in your comment you don't have the leading slash on windows. Both of these could be causing errors or a mistype could have easily occurred.

Comment: My bad I miss read the last part of you q. Have you tried mounting the disk without specifying the file system ( aka no -t ntfs ).

Comment: @LamarB: yes, I have but then it complains about the type like this `root@h:/# mount /dev/sdb2 /Windows/
mount: you must specify the filesystem type`.

Comment: adding -o debug may provide more information

Comment: @LamarB: Tried that but cannot find anything meaninful with the bebug flag. I opened a chat to the U site [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3716101#3716101) addressing this issue -- perhaps I should ask more clarified q there. We now know that it is NTFS but not why this laplink mounting is not working.

Comment: What does `sudo file -s /dev/sdb2` show?

Comment: @Gilles: `$ sudo file -s /dev/sdb2
/dev/sdb2: data`

Comment: @hhh You don't seem to have a filesystem there, at least not something Linux can recognized. Even if the partition table says “HPFS/NTFS/exFAT”, that might not reflect its content. Is it an encrypted disk? What is on this disk when you view it from Windows?

Comment: @Gilles: ...and interestingly `$ sudo file -s /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb: x86 boot sector; partition 1: ID=0x7, active, starthead 32, startsector 2048, 3072000 sectors; partition 2: ID=0x7, starthead 89, startsector 3074048, 597489664 sectors; partition 3: ID=0x7, starthead 254, startsector 600563712, 24576000 sectors, code offset 0xe`

Comment: @Gilles: When I plug this disk into X220, it boots as W7Pro and it is the genuine fresh OS just from box (ok I installed cygwin but that doees not count...)...perhaps I need to restart and try this again?

Comment: @hhh You have 3 partitions on that disk, presumably the OS is on one of the other two. The output of `file -s /dev/sdb` looks normal.

Answer (score 1):

You can clone the whole drive to an image file with `dd`, you can even compress it to save space:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb2 | bzip2 >~/old-disk.img.bz2
```

If you have [`pv`](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml), you can even get a progress bar:

```
sudo pv /dev/sdb2 | bzip2 >~/old-disk.img.bz2
```

Comment: +1 for the clever idea to use compression, hopefully saves time..

Comment: It won't save time, it'll save storage!

Comment: ...I think I need to plug in Rsync somewhere, it takes 30hours -- I have disk that is 60GB used but apparently about 300Gb free space (not sur but takes more than expected), researching the way to user rsync.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `NTFS-3G`, note **3G**.

This should do the trick:

`$ mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb2 /mnt/point`

I regularly use this to mount my external hard drive with a Server 2008 R2 virtual hard disk on it under Debian Squeeze.

Comment: `root@xfz:/# mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb2 /Windows/
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb2': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb2' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?` -- well the same err. Even same err with sdb1, sdb --.

Comment: Try `$ ntfs-3g /dev/sdb2 /mount_point` ?

Comment: `root@xfz:/# ntfs-3g /dev/sdb2 /Windows/
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb2': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb2' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?`, I forget to mention -- I tried this one already -- the same err?!

Answer (score 0):

The mount command should have /host and /Windows like this /host/Windows/. try it.