# W7 Paint -software does not start up

Tags: windows-7, image-editing

Usually, I do not use W machine but I have to use W machine because it is supported with a duplex scanner (same as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100990/cross-platform-duplex-scanner-with-good-support-in-ubuntu)). I need to do fast image editing with it and the Paint is the software I use while on W7. Could someone explain how can I get paint working back?

My X220 machine got killed due to low battery while paint was running -- and now apparently Paint got corrupted and so Paint does not start anymore. How to fix this?

Comment: Is **W** short for Windows? What happens when you launch paint? An error? Nothing at all? Can you browse to the folder containing `mspaint` and double-click it there? Is there anything in the Windows event logs?

Comment: @IanBoyd: nothing, corrupted Paint (dot).

Comment: Was it a message saying something about Paint was corrupted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

> sfc /scannow

In an elevated command prompt and if it is corrupted, it will ask for the Windows 7 DVD, insert it.

Also make sure you run the

> chkdsk /F

as Administrator and schedule an Disk Check.

Comment: He should also update his anti-virus software, run a virus scan, and download Malwarebytes to check for malware.

Comment: @IanBoyd are all W users this paranoia, sorry I am totally newbie here but suggesting viruses is a bit off. Sounds a bit odd, I think the case must have something to do with corrupted paint, hard to believe malware. I want to keep my W machine simple without much modifications.

Comment: @IanBoyd hhh is right, it cannot be malware.

Comment: @hhh Right Click cmd > Ran As Administrator

Comment: Irony is that my X220 did not come with any DVD or anything like that, I have no backup media of this machine, shortly. It has been on my TODO -list but postponed it to clone this machine, more [here](http://superuser.com/questions/397646/cloning-fresh-windows-7-fsed-hdd-to-linux-server-because-having-no-external-hdd).

Comment: @hhh or do this http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/run-a-command-as-administrator-from-the-windows-vista-run-box/

Comment: Thank you, the one-liners were enough to fix the problem. Happy hxcking!

Comment: @hhh :) :) :) :)

Comment: You are probably the guy able to handle this situation as well [here](http://superuser.com/questions/415932/fixing-corrupted-windows-7-professional-most-drivers-stopped-working-and-starti), it is getting interesting with this machine :P