# Cloning Fresh Windows 7 with external HDD, DVD or CDs?

Tags: windows-7, backup, clone

I want to create Windows installation disk (not necessarily CD) from my Windows 7 Pro laptop, not sure what it actually means here. The material is about 50-60GB, requiring about 12 pcs of 5GB disk (not going to happen, too much work to use them later). I have the Windows serial on the laptop bottom and this is so-called firm -laptop (no idea what it actually mean, better warranty and some instant support thing apparently). Now

1. how to do the clone with external material such as DVDs?
2. how can I create mock-windows-installation medium or some real windows-installation medium?

I am now not sure whether Windows offers W7 -installations medium online, well my W -peer mentioned some MSDAA -something.

**Perhaps related**

1. [Cloning Fresh Windows 7 -fsed HDD to Linux Server because having no external HDD or disks for the Backup](https://superuser.com/questions/397646/cloning-fresh-windows-7-fsed-hdd-to-linux-server-because-having-no-external-hdd)

Answer (score 3):

Why not just create a backup image - Win 7 will do that for you - Control Panel - Backup & Restore - Create System Image. You can store it on an external HDD. You can also create a repair boot disk from which you will be able to restore the image file.

Comment: ...it is at least 50GB, I have no external HDD available, currently. I wish there was some easier way for this, not over 10 backup disks. I find it odd if W does not provide anything online, odd.

Comment: @hhh - 50GB online backup?! I'd love to see anybody who can provide a free service like that!  Anyway, this is the correct and really only reasonable way to do this.  Buy an external hard disk, they are VERY cheap.  (Alternatively, Windows Backup does support BD-Rs if you have a Blu-Ray drive kicking around somewhere...you'd probably only need two disks for that).  Your real problem is simply the fact that it's very large - you need media of comparable size, period.

Comment: Does your laptop come with repair disks/restore partition. If so rely on this for your system/program files and just back up your personal data. This is probably already around 20Gb of your 50Gb so the external HDD is probably still the best/cheapest option (if you do weekly backups).