# Restoring Windows to new Lenovo Thinkpad after installing different OS to it?

Tags: windows, installation, debian, thinkpad

I installed Debian to Windows Lenovo Thinkpad. Now I want to get the Windows back. How can I do it?

My friend mentioned something about partitions, below my comp X220 details.

```
$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00081865

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1       38052   305647616   83  Linux
/dev/sda2           38052       38914     6921217    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5           38052       38914     6921216   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

**Perhaps related**

> - [Cloning Fresh Windows 7 -fsed HDD to Linux Server because having no external HDD or disks for the Backup](https://superuser.com/questions/397646/cloning-fresh-windows-7-fsed-hdd-to-linux-server-because-having-no-external-hdd)
> - 6th March 2012 chat in Unix Stackexchange between Kevin, Gilles -- and me.

Comment: Looks like you overwrote your recovery partition...  Did you make a backup of the discs first (or did your laptop come with recovery discs separate)?  I know my lenovo prompted me to make DVD copies of the recovery upon first boot.  Otherwise, you will have to call Lenovo to get the OEM discs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry buddy, It seems you have deleted the Windows Partition. You can only bring it back with hard disk recover programs. But you can not boot it again.

Comment: ...good idea: recover program, I may find it that way -- any idea of the filename to look for?

Comment: You don't have to know the filename, When you start the recover program it recovers all the files on the disk. Then you select and recover the files you want. But if the OS's write data on windows's files you can not recover them.

Comment: @hhh - You won't be able to recover the data, at least not ALL the data, which means the recovery image is gone.  The solution is to purchase and install Windows yourself and/or contact Lenovo for a replacement recovery image.

Comment: Roger, moved the data-recovery -queston [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56804/data-recovery-programs-in-unix).

Answer (score 0):

I totally forgot! I did backups with SATA/IDE -device [here](http://www.dealextreme.com/p/21571?r=36798618). I also did some sort of backups to my server but cannot remember whether it finished, it took quite long time to backup 320GB disk.

This writing is still in progress but trying to outline my restoration of Windows. I don't know yet whether it succeed or not, the current problem looks to be that OSx is unable to read backup images created with Ubuntu -laptop or Obsd -computer. I have something on the disks, not sure yet whether readable backup -images.

[image]

[image]

For the irony of Life, I even have well-documented material how I did the backups -- more [here](https://superuser.com/questions/397646/cloning-fresh-windows-7-fsed-hdd-to-linux-server-because-having-no-external-hdd). I backuped the disks with Kevin's commands:

> sudo dd if=/dev/sdb2 | bzip2 >~/old-disk.img.bz2
>
> sudo pv /dev/sdb2 | bzip2 >~/old-disk.img.bz2

Now the task is of course to locate the files, they may be in my harddrives or in my server. You can read our chat [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3716098#3716098) and my follow-up [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7018922#7018922).

derobert instructed

> $ bzcat ~/old-disk.img.bz2 | pv > /dev/sdb2

`"that'd put it back on /dev/sdb2 (which needs to already be set up to be the same size or larger). Note that is a partition image, not a disk image."`

Comment: Moved the next puzzle [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7018922#7018922) about restoring the backup. The 6th March 2012 contains the chat discussion in Unix Stackexchange related to the backuping things.